# function with monad writer does not return result

Tags: haskell

I was trying to implement `fixed point` function  as the below

```
fixedPoint  :: (Fractional a,Ord a ) => (a  -> a ) -> a -> a 
fixedPoint f initialGuess= let x= f initialGuess
                       in if (closeEnough initialGuess x) 
                       then x
                       else fixedPoint f x
```

this function works perfectly when calling it for `fixedPoint cos 1` and return `0.7390851699445544` however, I wanted to log the steps done by the function and add it into in string using the writer monad, the adjusted function is as per the below

```
fixedPoint'  :: (Fractional a,Ord a,Show a) => (a -> a ) -> a -> Writer [String] a 
fixedPoint' f initialGuess= 
let x = f initialGuess 
in 
if (closeEnough initialGuess x ) then
  do
    tell ["Ending with" ++ show initialGuess]
    return x
else
  do
    result <- fixedPoint' f x
    tell ["Trying Guess" ++ show initialGuess]
    return result
```

when calling the function `mapM_ putStrLn $ snd $ runWriter (fixedPoint' cos 1)` it return the empty tuple

Comment: Your identation is the only thing that looks wrong. Otherwise, this works for me

Comment: in which block?

Comment: I think your `let` should be on the same line as the `=`. In your place, however, I would just use a `where` instead of a `let`.

Comment: Do you always want to log the steps, or just for now? Otherwise you could use `trace`.

Comment: I want always to log the steps

Comment: Also works for me, after indenting everything after `let x = ...`.  Yes the type of `mapM_ putStrLn $ snd $ runWriter (fixedPoint' cos 1)` is `IO ()` so it will always "return" the empty tuple, but there should be some output, too.  Would you mind posting a transcript of your ghci session or however you run this?

Comment: do you mean by session the version of GHC, if yes , I am using Haskell for Mac editor which uses GHC compiler version 7.10.3

Comment: Call the function this way instead: `let (result, report) = runWriter (fixedPoint' cos 1) in mapM_ putStrLn report >> return result`.